# JQUERY AJAX POST is not displaying RESPONSE, but returns HTTP 200

Tags: php, web-config, iis-8.5

Working on my locale machine, but not on server, so I suspect it has to do with *.htaccess set-up

Posts are going through, states http 200 in firebug, but there are no response tab. it's like the response is being disregarded. on my locale device this is not an issue.

environment:

- IIS 8.5
- PHP
- JQuery Min 1.11.1

(I did not choose this, it was the project I jumped into, this was previously working, but now feels dead in the water)

Here is the AJAX Call via function when button is pushed:

```
function profileUpdate(){
    clearMessageContainers();
    // do other things for a valid form
    var formData = new FormData();
    formData.append("user_fname","John");
    formData.append("user_lname","Doe");
    formData.append("community","Springfield");
    formData.append("region","Bruce County");
    formData.append("type","update_profile")
    //console.log(formData);
   // alert("submitHandler");
    //form.submit();
    $.ajax({ 
       url: '/profile/edit/update_profile',
       type: 'POST',
       data: formData,
       processData: false,
       contentType: false,
       success: function(msg){
           $("#successContainer").append(msg);

       }
        ,error: 
            function(xmlHttpRequest, status, error){
                                                            a(xmlHttpRequest + "| ajax failure: upload photo | " + status + " | error:" + error);

            var xmlHttpRequestStr = "";
            for(var x in xmlHttpRequest)
                    xmlHttpRequestStr = xmlHttpRequestStr + xmlHttpRequest[x];

            console.log(xmlHttpRequestStr);
            }

    });
 }
```

in ajaxHandler.php

```
//simple test to confirm it made it
echo "made it";
var_dump($_POST); exit();
```

*.htaccess is defined like so, and is imported into URL Rewrites of IIS

```
RewriteEngine on
# If it does not exist as a directory 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
# Line below prevents POSTS from being overwritten
#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} !POST  
#RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]
#RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^.*profile/edit/(.*)$ /templates/ajaxHandler.php?type=$1
```

This is all working fine on my local dev, but I am using apache, I read about :

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} !POST
```

To allow the site to not ignore or redirect POST

Can anyone help me pin point the issue? I would appreciate it.

Here is an image capture of Firebug, Local Dev is on top, Server Post is on Bottom, note the Response tab is missing.

[image]

**SOLUTION - This was a server config issue**

- Create new project in ineptpub, transfer project
- Create new website in IIS Manager, pointing at new project folder above
- Create new host for website (this was host a, option under existing host)
- This fixed the issue which magically appeared - stressful 2 days are now over.

Comment: well, you are forcing a clientside (301) redirect to your php script, so even if the ajax stuff is working correctly, PHP won't see it as anything other than a $_GET requests, which means $_POST will be an empty array.

Comment: @MarcB I tried removing the R=301 and still I have the same issue, no response is being displayed.

Comment: Even if the $_POST is an empty array wouldn't I get a response which has "made it"

Comment: that too. I'd suggest bypassing the ajax stuff completely and just whipping up a plain html form to do the post stuff while you figure out what's going on. ajax is the bee's knees, but it's also a pain the rump to debug when things go wrong, especially if you're mixing in redirects/rewrites.

Comment: Can't bypass it. AJAX has been utilized throughout the whole project and was working, now it's not, and I'm thinking did I or someone else make a change to the server.  :s

Comment: @MarcB Should web.config be set up to allow POST and GET?